# Creating multiple cookie contexts using the `fetch` API

Tags: javascript, fetch, session-cookies

I am writing a Web Extension that attempts to fetch pages from a session based API in parallel. The API uses cookies to store the session information. So, the following sequence of commands would work:

```js
// Fetch sequence 1
await fetch("https://url.endpoint/start_session");
const usefulData1 = await fetch("https://url.endpoint/navigate_to_X",
  { credentials: "include" });
// Fetch sequence 2
await fetch("https://url.endpoint/start_session");
const usefulData2 = await fetch("https://url.endpoint/navigate_to_Y",
  { credentials: "include" });
```

I would like to run *Fetch sequence 1* and *Fetch sequence 2* in parallel. The problem is, every time I access `https://url.endpoint/start_session` I get sent back a new set of cookies, and all fetch requests with `{ credentials: "include" }` use the currently set cookies (which get overridden when `start_session` returns).

My question is: is there a way to set up multiple "sessions" so that these requests can run in parallel with their own cookies? Or is there some other workaround? (It appears the `fetch` api will not allow you to get or set the `Set-Cookie` header manually...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to await the completion of two promises at once, you can use `Promise.all`. This will create a new promise that only resolves when all promises passed in to it complete, but still lets them run in parallel. In this case, I would await the `start_session` endpoint, then await a `Promise.all` of the other two, like this:

```
await fetch("https://url.endpoint/start_session");
const [usefulData1, usefulData2] = await Promise.all([
  fetch("https://url.endpoint/navigate_to_X", { credentials: "include" }),
  fetch("https://url.endpoint/navigate_to_Y", { credentials: "include" })
])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. I simplified the situation for the post, but there are multiple `navigates*` that need to be called in sequence before the final page I with the data.

Comment: Do they overwrite the cookies each other depends on? There's nothing conceptually stopping you from wrapping each fetch in another await function, where you do the series of awaits necessary within those promises. If they overwrite the cookies each depends on, you cannot run them in parallel as they are effectively modifying shared state.

Comment: Yes. They're overriding the cookies. It's quite annoying...